# Copy data from Excel to Powerpoint in a specified template format., but in the image it gives a "?" in random places

Tags: excel, vba, copy, powerpoint

[image]
I am trying to generate PPT in a specific format for some data in Excel, my code is working as expected but in some random places it gives a "?" in between sentences/at the start of sentence/at the end of sentence.

```
Sub Generate_RR_All_PPTs()
Dim myFile, Fileselected As String, Path As String, objPPT As Object
Dim ppApp   As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
ppApp.Presentations.Open 
Filename:="C:\Release_Review\EBU_ReleaseReviewReport.pptx"  ' 
Dim j As Long
Worksheets("RR").Select
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For j = 1 To NumRows - 1
  Worksheets("RR").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.Copy

 Worksheets("Release Review").Select

     Range("u1").Select

     'Selection.Paste
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(1)

ppPres.Slides(1).Copy


ppPres.Slides.Paste Index:=ppPres.Slides.Count + 1


Set activeSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count)
activeSlide.Select
'Step 4: Copy the range as a picture
 Sheets("Release Review").Range("A3:Q30").Copy   
 DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents

'Step 5: Paste the picture and adjust its position

 activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture

      Next 'select next item in the list

 ppApp.Activate

 Set activeSlide = Nothing
 Set ppPres = Nothing
 Set ppApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

I expect the template from excel to be copied in image format and pasted in powerpoint, it is working as expected except for the few random "?" symbol.

Comment: Your excel cell has some unprintable charater after `enhancement` or before `Mol` And hence you are getting those "??"

Comment: `ppPasteBitmap` instead of `ppPasteMetafilePicture` will paste it as an image without those "??". If you still want `ppPasteMetafilePicture`, then clean your text in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Siddharth, I replaced these two lines and now it is working as expected . 
Sheets("Release Review").Range("A3:Q30").CopyPicture
  DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
DoEvents
activeSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select